# How to pass a timezone format file to a naive datetime object in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timezone

I am trying to compare a naive `datetime` object with a timezone aware `datetime` object.

I have to change.

Initially I was getting this error:

```
lastDate = start_date + ' ' + errorTime
lastDate = datetime.strptime(lastDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
time_diff = lastDate - FirstDate
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

Firstly... I checked the tzinfo of my two datetime objects..

```
>>>FirstDate.tzinfo
>>>tzfile(u'/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London')

>>>lastDate.tzinfo
>>>
```

This is expected since `lastDate` is tz unaware.

I then imported `pytz` and converted the naive `lastDate` datetime object:

```
lastDate = start_date + ' ' + errorTime
lastDate = datetime.strptime(lastDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
lastDate = pytz.timezone('Europe/London').localize(lastDate)
time_diff = lastDate - FirstDate
TypeError: Timestamp subtraction must have the same timezones or no timezones
```

Checking the timezones again I have:

```
>>>FirstDate.tzinfo
>>>tzfile(u'/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London')

>>>lastDate.tzinfo
>>><DstTzInfo 'Europe/London' GMT0:00:00 STD>
```

I'm stumped... how do I give the naive datetime object `lastDate` a tzfile?

Note: I must convert the naive `datetime` object `lastDate` to match the tz aware `datetime` object `FirstDate`. I can't amend the tz of the `FirstDate`.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work this way:

```
lastDate = lastDate.replace(tzinfo=FirstDate.tzinfo)
lastDate - FirstDate
```

Replacing only the `tzinfo` attribute on the naive datetime

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the timezone from an existing `datetime` and apply to another.  Try:

```
lastDate = FirstDate.tzinfo.localize(lastDate)
```

instead of:

```
lastDate = pytz.timezone('Europe/London').localize(lastDate)
```

that should do what you are after.

Comment: Hi @Stephen I tried this and now I'm getting the following error:
`AttributeError: 'tzfile' object has no attribute 'localize'`